# Linear regression with tf-idf transformation

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression, tf-idf

I have two dataframes, the former contains > 700 predictors in columns and the latter contains one column. The former is used as predictors (all with values 0 and 1 but mostly 0 because of sparsity) and the second as the response for model training and testing.  The first one has name `ser` and the second one `star`.

I use the following for tf-idf transformation

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
transformer = TfidfTransformer()

A = transformer.fit_transform(ser)
```

The following shows part of `print(A)`

```
 (0, 302)   0.613133438876
 (0, 202)   0.789979358042
 (1, 556)   1.0
 (2, 556)   0.432375068194
 (2, 17)    0.901693850708
 (3, 556)   0.269567465847
 (3, 335)   0.671245025218
 (3, 256)   0.400099662956
 (3, 238)   0.562746618986
 (4, 556)   0.401348891903
 (4, 137)   0.915925251846
 (5, 641)   0.785485510985
 (5, 396)   0.618880046562
 (6, 317)   0.525163047715
 (6, 305)   0.851001629443
 ... (more are cut)
```

Did I use this tf-idf transformation all right? As I have the following, I receive the error that I will post at the end of the post.

```
star = pd.DataFrame({"star": star})
data = pd.concat([ser, star], axis = 1)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

D = LinearRegression()

Dfit = D.fit(ser, star, sample_weight = A)
Dpred = D.predict(ser)
Dscore = D.score(ser,star)
print(Dscore)
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "categories_model.py", line 67, in <module>
Dfit = D.fit(ser, star, sample_weight = A)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 434, in fit
sample_weight=sample_weight)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 127, in center_data
X_mean = np.average(X, axis=0, weights=sample_weight)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 937, in average
"1D weights expected when shapes of a and weights differ.")
TypeError: 1D weights expected when shapes of a and weights differ.
```

Could anyone help me understand all of this and how to improve the code? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from misplacing the transformed matrix. This solves the problem.

```
Dfit = D.fit(A, star)
```